# UserImpersonation, act one user as another

Tags: c#, wcf, config, impersonation

I need to create a setting from the config file for user impersonation, but I need to specify the "domain\username" without a password.

For example something like: < add user="abc\user1" asUser = "abc\user2">
And basically the User2 will have all the rights and posibilities from User1.

I've looked over for similar questions, but can't find this specific one.

Comment: Normally it would be bad form to be able to impersonate a user without any form of password - in what context are you needing this

Comment: This is for a test environment, where some users should have the access for testing this, but only for a limited time, and instead giving them the rights, I would need to assign him and act like other user.